# Skip line using File.ReadAllLines if it equals a particular string

Tags: c#, csv, readline

Is it possible to do `string[] CSV_file = File.ReadAllLines(@..\..\..\Data.csv").Skip()`
and instead of hardcoding a line into e.g. Skip(1) it skips a line where it equals a string.
Say the csv file is:

hello, sam

hello, joe

no

hello, ben

no

and you want to skip every line that says 'no' so you're left with just the three hello's
is this possible to do like the code below or another way.

`string[] CSV_file = File.ReadAllLines(@..\..\..\Data.csv").Skip(alllines).Equals("No");`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `Where` to filter lines by some condition, -> `File.ReadAllLines("file").Where(line => line.Equals("No") == false).ToArray();`

Comment: `string[] CSV_file = File.ReadAllLines(@..\..\..\Data.csv").Where(line => line != "No").ToArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Where` extension method instead, with this method you can filter lines by some condition. In your case condition would be *not equal "No"*.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file")
    .Where(line => line.Equals("No") == false)
    .ToArray();
```

To check only first column, change condition to check that line doesn't start with "no,"

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file")
    .Where(line => line.StartsWith("no,") == false)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: what about if the string no also has test after like no, text1, text2 can you just get the first column

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified code from above

```
string[] CSV_file = File.ReadAllLines("file").Where(l => !l.StartsWith("No")).ToArray();
```

Comment: What is modified from the answer above? it is exactly same logic ;) Except this approach will "skip" lines which starts with something else than "no", for example "November" will be filtered out as well